# apipie: describe the return of an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apipie

Using [apipie-rails](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails), I would like to describe the response of an array of strings.

```
# GET /api/v1/some_strings.json
["Foo", "Bar"]
```

I was thinking of describing the response like this:

```rb
api :GET "/api/v1/some_strings.json"
returns array_of: String, code: 200
def index
  return json: ["Foo", "Bar"]
end
```

However, I'm getting the following runtime error:

```
RuntimeError:
  No param_group or self-describing class named String
```

From the [response-description documentation](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails#id26) it looks like this is not supported by this dsl.

I was wondering whether there is another syntax to describe the desired response.

Or is returning an array of strings considered an anti-pattern and I should instead refactor the api structure itself?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [this](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails#example-5) example, I would try this:

```rb
api :GET "/api/v1/some_strings.json"
returns array_of: String
def index
  render JSON(["Foo", "Bar"])
end
```

By the way, if the status code that you want to return it's `200`, you don't have to specify it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow!  I‘m not sure I understand your suggestion. The line that raises the exception is ˋreturns array_of: Stringˋ. Sending the json response does work.

Comment: Have you tried changing `array_of: String` for `:array_of => String`?